# Time frame for the question

Tags: discussion

If we ask question in Drupal Answers site and we did not get answers or any response on question for 3-4 days, should we ask new question for the same or need to wait more.

I know that if a user knows the solution for the question, then he will surely response in Drupal Answers. But If a question did not get response for 3-4 days, then this question will not be top of the question list in Drupal answers. So may be some one who has solution for the question do not check question. 
If we ask a new question for the same problem, then it would be duplicate question.

Please suggest what should we do in this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get more response until i get the correct solution?](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2440/how-do-i-get-more-response-until-i-get-the-correct-solution)

Comment: @Bala while indeed connected, these questions aren't duplicates the way I see it. You are asking for ways to get more answers, OP asks when it's OK to repost. His reason is similar, but question a significant bit different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If we ask a new question for the same problem, then it would be duplicate question.

It certainly would be - please don't do that, it'll just get deleted :) The length of time is irrelevant, if you duplicate a question of your own from 6 months ago it will still be closed/deleted.

If your question is not receiving the attention you think it should be there are a couple of options open to you:

1. Improve the question by editing it. This will help to clarify what you're asking, and also move the question to the front page. Please don't make edits just to bump the post up though - make sure your edits are substantial and are actually an improvement to the question.
2. Offer a [bounty](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/bounty). This will promote your question for 7 days, giving it the extra exposure you're looking for. The extra points a user would earn for answering also serves as an extra incentive, which works in your favour.

Comment: If I will offer a bounty, then it will deduct some points from my account.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola Correct, that's by design. You can choose between 50 and 500 of your own reputation to offer for the bounty

Comment: Thanks for information. I will surely offer bounty if I need response more frequently.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola Be careful with bounties; if you don't give sufficient information, users are still not able to answer it correctly. Offering a bounty should be the last resort, when nothing else worked. Bounties increase also the noise, as there are users who post a wild guess, hoping to get at least two up-votes, and get the automatically assigned bounty (half of the bounty offered from the user who asked the question).

Comment: @kiamlaluno, OK. I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 4):

To add what @Clive said, since re-asking the same question after X days just for the fact the previous question didn't get an answer is not acceptable, you should:

- Make sure you tagged the question with the correct tags
- Make sure you added all the necessary details that could help the users who can answer it; if you have details to add after you asked the question, add them
- Make sure not to add details that are not pertinent to the question, and which could confuse the users who can answer
- If the question is about code, make sure to add the relevant parts of that code
- If you did any research, make sure to show what you found; this helps to avoid suggesting something you already tried, and it avoids the question is seen as "do my work for me" kind of question

If you don't add enough information to your question, and users keep asking you in comments to get the information it is necessary to answer it, chances are the users will quickly lose their interest in answering the question. A question that is detailed enough, and which shows the search done from the beginning has more chances to get an answer.
Clearly, the users who ask questions don't necessarily know which details are required to answer or give a better answer, but I would avoid asking "I want to do this; how can I achieve it?" questions as those are probably between the less interesting questions, when the question doesn't provide the required details, especially because answers should not be guesses, and users avoid answering when they are not 98% sure what the question is describing.

Comment: Thanks for your detail response. I will keep this in mind when ask any question in Drupal Answer.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola what kiamlaluno says, users who ask and then does not provide details they are asked for was almost a plague some time ago, [see here](http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/q/2633/16495). Please don't become one of them ;)

Comment: @Molot, Sure, I will not follow those people. I am new in Drupal Answer site, so I am learning how to use this site.